# Entity Framework - DB First - Multiplicity constraint violated, The role X of the relationship Y has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

Using DB first (EF 6), I created a 1 parent - 2 child relationship. Student_Temp is the parent object and Marks as a child with 1 or 0..1 relationship.

Student_Temp.cs is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Student_Temp
{
    public Student_Temp()
    {
        this.Marks = new HashSet<Mark>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
}
```

And Mark.cs is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Mark
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Marks { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student_Temp Student_Temp { get; set; }
}
```

And the updation code is as below:

```
using (DBContext = new SampleEntities1())
            {
                student_Temp = DBContext.Student_Temp.Include(T => T.Marks).FirstOrDefault(S => S.StudentId == selectedStudentId);

                student_Temp.Name = txtName.Text;

                student_Temp.Marks.Clear();
                student_Temp.Marks = mark;

                foreach (var TP in student_Temp.Marks.ToList())
                {
                    if (TP.Id > 0)
                    {
                        Mark M = student_Temp.Marks.FirstOrDefault(T => T.Id == TP.Id);

                        M.Marks = Convert.ToInt32(txtMarks.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //student_Temp.Marks.Add(TP);
                        DBContext.Marks.Add(TP);
                    }
                }

                DBContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

While updating existing Student record, if i add a new record in Mark collection then i'm getting the above error. I've googled so much but could not find the proper solution.

Comment: Seems that you need to create new copy of each `Mark` entity before inserting: `DBContext.Marks.Add(new Mark() { Id = TP.Id, SubjectName = TP.SubjectName, ... });`, or alternatively create a collection of `Student_Temp` inside `Mark` entity: `public virtual ICollection<Student_Temp> Student_Temps { get; set; }`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it is not working. I am still receiving the same error.